# Cannot patch Kubernetes node using python kubernetes-client library

Tags: json, python-3.x, kubernetes-python-client

I'm trying to patch a kube node using the Python [kubernetes-client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/CoreV1Api.md) library.

Specifically, I'm trying to cordon the node. Using kubectl, I'm able to do it successfully:

```
kubectl patch node mynode -json --patch={"op":"replace", "path":"/spec/unschedulable", "value":true}`
```

But using the python kubernetes-client library fails:

```
from kubernetes import client, config

config.load_kube_config()
body='{"op":"replace", "path":"/spec/unschedulable", "value":true}'
# also have tried body='[{"op":"replace", "path":"/spec/unschedulable", "value":true}]'
v1=client.CoreV1Api()
ret=v1.patch_node(name="mynode", body=body)
print (ret)
```

The return contains the message:

```
"json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type jsonpatch.Patch"
```

Some research led me to [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/68861) bug. It refers to using the kubernetes api directly, but the issue appears to be the same. Unfortunately, the solution - passing an array - doesn't help.

Unfortunately, the documentation doesn't help, here. The required type for `body` is shown as `UNKNOWN_BASE_TYPE`, which is not useful. I've looked at the [code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-client/python/master/kubernetes/client/api/core_v1_api.py), but there's no clue there as to how I should be formatting the body - I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, it turns out that `json.loads()` is the answer, and upper casing the bool, so that `loads()` works.
Also, although a non-array body does not raise an error, neither does it actually make the desired change, so an array is required:

```
from kubernetes import client, config
import json

config.load_kube_config()
v1=client.CoreV1Api()

body='[{"op": "add", "path": "/spec/unschedulable", "value": True}]'
print(json.loads(body)) #Debug
ret=v1.patch_node(name="mynode", body=json.loads(body))
print (ret)
```

It's worth pointing out that the resulting body has the bool capitalised, whereas for the kubectl command-line operation it must be lower-case.

Also, oddly, if I replace:
`body=json.loads(body)`
with
`body="[{'op': 'add', 'path': '/spec/unschedulable', 'value': False}]"`

Which is the output of the earlier print statement, it fails in the original manner.

Answer (score 2):

This can be also implemented that way

```
from kubernetes import client, config
config.load_incluster_config()
body = {
    "spec": {
        "unschedulable": True
    }
}
api_response = client.CoreV1Api().patch_node("NODE_NAME", body)
print(api_response)
```

This way is in case you load the config internally in the cluster.
If you want to run from outside of the cluster, the config can be load like that

```
config_file = open(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + "config.yaml", 'r')    
config.load_kube_config(config_file)
```